# Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined] at Route.(anonymous function) [as post]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to confirm if a user has admin privilages.  When I call the `verifyAdminUser` function from my router I get this error:

> Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined] at Route.(anonymous function) [as post]

Here is my call from my router file

```
.post(Verify.verifyAdminUser, function (req, res, next) {})
```

and my verify function

```
verifyAdminUser = function (req, res, next) {}
```

Can anyone help me with this?  I have read many similar questions but none of them have helped.

Comment: Here is what I have for the function:

Comment: exports.verifyAdminUser = function (req, res, next) {

    if(req.decoded._doc.admin != 'true'){
        var err = new Error('You are not an admin user!');
        err.status = 401;
        return next(err);
    } else {        
        return next();
    }    
};

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `Verify.verifyAdminUser` is declared and `!== void 0`

Express does this, with `handle` being each argument of `post()`:

```
 if (typeof handle !== 'function') {
    var type = toString.call(handle);
    var msg = 'Route.' + method + '() requires callback functions but got a ' + type;
    throw new Error(msg);
  }
```

Comment: ok I have the following function in my verify file working, but as soon as I change the name, I get an error saying its not a function but an object.


works:
exports.verifyOrdinaryUser = function (req, res, next) {}
};

doesnt work:
exports.verifyAdminUser = function (req, res, next) {}
};

Comment: That is weird!! Do you have a gist?

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved this.  My require statement wasn't pointing to the correct path

```
var Verify = require('../verify');
```

But that doesn't tell me why it worked for this

```
.post(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, function (req, res, next) {}
```

but not this

```
.post(Verify.verifyOrdinaryUser, Verify.verifyAdminUser, function (req, res, next) {}
```

when both functions are in the same file